# date_create_from_format php on certain month and date does not return correct date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a function in php that uses the date_create_from_format function to convert dates in format 'Ym' to datetime. It works correctly except in one case I found today and I cant find the problem. The situation is the following:

**Current date: 07/31/2014.**

**$period value: '201409'** (as the month I want to do some calc on)

```
$newDateCreated = date_create_from_format('Ym', $period);
```

This returns a new datetime created but with the value of 10/01/2014 instead of 09/01/2014

If instead of setting the value 201409 I put 201411 or 201408 the new datetime is created correctly.

The only solution I found to this was to replace

```
$newDateCreated = date_create_from_format('Ym', $period);
```

for

```
$newDateCreated = date_create_from_format('Ymd', $period.'01');
```

I believe that this have to be something with the day of the month but I cant find the real problem. Any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022411/is-this-a-php-date-bug-or-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-code/25022452#25022452

Comment: Thanks John but I believe that this is not the same case as I am not adding or diminishing the date. I only want to get a date according the string given

Comment: It is the same issue as it has to do with the fact that the current day of the month doesn't exist in the other month so one gets skipped.

Comment: I just received a solution related to what you mentioned. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the
>   generated time which are not specified in format will be set to the
>   current system time.
>
> If format contains the character !, then portions of the generated
>   time not provided in format, as well as values to the left-hand side
>   of the !, will be set to corresponding values from the Unix epoch.
>
> The Unix epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Example

```
date_create_from_format('Ym', '201409');

// Tries '2014-09-31 15:59:45', but since that date doesn't exists 
// that becomes '2014-10-01':
// object(DateTime)#62 (3) {
//  ["date"] => string(19) "2014-10-01 15:59:45"
//  ["timezone_type"] => int(3)
//  ["timezone"] => string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
// }

date_create_from_format('!Ym', '201409');

// object(DateTime)#62 (3) {
//  ["date"] => string(19) "2014-09-01 00:00:00"
//  ["timezone_type"] => int(3)
//  ["timezone"] => string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
// }
```