# PHP DateTime return not exepected result

Tags: php, date, datetime, compare

I'm trying to get -2 month on a Date in PHP.
Most of the time, the result is good, but for one date, the result is false.

```
$d = 1409436000;    // 31-8-2014

$d1 = new DateTime(date("d-m-Y", $d));

$d1->modify("-2 month");

echo $d1->format("d-m-Y");

// expected : 30-06-2014
// got      : 01-07-2014
```

My current PHP version is : 5.6.23-0+deb8u1
I don't have make any configuration about TimeZone.

So : Why did i get this result ? It is because August&July have 31days ? Or a current bug on the phpversion ? The TimeZone ?

Thanks =)

Comment: Is working for me.. I got 30-06-2014

Comment: You can try: `$d = 1409436000;    // 31-8-2014

$d1 = new DateTime();
$d1->setTimestamp($d);
$d1->modify("-2 month");

echo $d1->format("d-m-Y");`

Comment: I actually got `01-07-2014` as well. I'm running PHP 7.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, ok i'm not alone =) That's not normal isn't it ?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022411/is-this-a-php-date-bug-or-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-code/25022452#25022452

Comment: So, according to that link, the first comment is the one that actually gets the wrong date? Regardless, it's kinda weird that some get one date and others get another?

Comment: Getting `30-06-2014` on PHP 5.6.23 and PHP 7.0.8. Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: MateiMihai not working too :/
MagnusEriksson yes ..
@syck => i said i have version : 5.6.23-0+deb8u1, the same as yours =)

Comment: according to linked article by @syck is clear problem with your 31.day, because there are months that do not have it.. version with 28. here: https://3v4l.org/caEm4 , in the question you write you expect 30.6. but you are realy getting 31.6. -> 1.7.

Comment: @Jimmmy yes, you're right, i tried with 31/12/2014 -1 month => getting 01/12/2014.

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 - Regardless, I still claim that it's weird that people get different results...

Comment: There was also a post, where someone looked it up in the PHP source and came to the conclusion that this is in fact intended behaviour. Cannot find it right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments and the links, i solved my problem this way :

```
$d = 1409436000;    // 31-8-2014

$d1 = strtotime("first day of this month", $d);
$d1 = strtotime("-2 month", $d1);
$d1 = strtotime("last day of this month", $d1);

echo date("d-m-Y", $d1);
```

- The way to be sure you will have the correct result is to take the
  first day from you're date.
- Make the stuff you need.
- Get the last day from current month back.

The problem was : 
I try to get "31/08/2014 -2 month" witch is equal to "31/06/2014".

31/06/2014 => this date don't exist and PHP will convert this to "01/07/2014"